# Keeping count of swaps in a bubble sort algorithm that uses recursion?

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting, recursion

```
def bubble_sort(a)
  something_changed = false
  swap = 0 
  a[0...-1].each_with_index do |num, i|
    if a[i] > a[i + 1]
      a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
      something_changed = true
      swap += 1
    end
  end
  bubble_sort(a)  if something_changed
  p swap
end

arr = [50, 60, 70, 20, 30, 10]
bubble_sort(arr)
# 0
# 1
# 1
# 3
# 3
# 3
```

So I have been at this for quite a while and tried it every which way.  I have managed to understand how the array gets sorted via bubble sort, and I know that for this particular array there are 11 substitutions that take place for the array to be sorted.  I can print out all the number of swaps per each time the method runs recursively, but for the life of me I can't get these numbers to group in to an array so I can add them and display 11, any insight would be great.  I've done the solution in python and it works fine, I just want to know if there is a way to group these numbers together as the method is running recursively. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do without the global variable:

```
def bubble_sort(a, swap_sum = 0)
  something_changed = false
  a[0...-1].each_with_index do |num, i|
    if a[i] > a[i + 1]
      a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
      something_changed = true
      swap_sum += 1
    end
  end
  something_changed ? bubble_sort(a, swap_sum) : swap_sum
end

arr = [50, 60, 70, 20, 30, 10]
bubble_sort(arr) #=> 11
```

Comment: Nice modification adding it as an argument, no need for the global array indeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count = []
def bubble_sort(a)
something_changed = false
swap = 0 
a[0...-1].each_with_index do |num, i|
  if a[i] > a[i + 1]
     a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
     something_changed = true
     swap += 1
  end
end
bubble_sort(a)  if something_changed
$count << swap
return $count.inject(:+)
end
arr = [50, 60, 70, 20, 30, 10]
p bubble_sort(arr) # 11
```

Never mind, turns out I was using p on the global variable I set up instead of return (something I was experimenting with earlier, not shown in above question). Now I am able to display just the number of substitutions.  Hope this helps someone down the line. Thanks for your time.